# How to update the content of wpf listbox from different window

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I've two windows: Main Window, Log Window. How can I update the listbox in the Log Window when some action is happened in the Main Window (e.g. button is clicked)?

Below is the code for listbox in Log Window:

```
<ListBox x:Name="DebugLogLb" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">  
  <TextBlock x:Name="DebugLogTb" Text="{Binding LogText}" Background="{x:Null}" />
</ListBox>
```

When the button in the Main Window is clicked, it will update the listbox. I tried with the code below but it doesn't work.

```
private void Btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var log = new LogWindow();
    log.DebugLogLb.Items.Add(new { LogText = "Button 1 is clicked" });
}
```

I'm able to update the listbox if I put everything in the same window, but I failed to do so with two windows.

My expected output would be like:
[image]

Even if both windows are opened, when the buttons in the Main Window are clicked, it will directly update in the Log Window as well.

Thanks for any helps in advanced.

Comment: Use some Event Aggregator framework like Calibur.Micro http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/

Comment: Do you create a new window every time a button is clicked?

Comment: @Ywah What is the type of `log.DebugLogLb.Items`? How do you bind your listbox to it(if you bind it)? Or do you aggregate all those items' texts into one text property? It is difficult to say what is going wrong with this code - it doesn't show much.

Comment: Hi @user2697817, no, I only want the window create one time, if I didn't open the Log Window, the event (button clicks) in the Main Window have to be updated in the Log Window.

Comment: Hi @Eugene Podskal, I bind the text to the listbox by using textblock. Is there any other better way to bind the text? I do not aggregate all those events (button clicks) into one property. Actually what I want is when Button 1 is clicked, "Button 1 is clicked" will be shown in the Log Window, next if Button 3 is clicked, "Button 3 is clicked" will be shown below the first one.

Comment: @Ywah Then what is the problem? What does or doesn't happen? Show the code and XAML related to modifiying `DebugLogTb`. And I've just seen it - you do not call `Show()` when creating new window. So you create new window each click and then do not show that window. You need to create LogWindow only once and show it. To interoperate between main and log you can either 1. Add **public** method to the `LogWindow` for modifying the log textbox. Store singular instance of it in main window and call this method each button click. 2. Or to use shared observable collection, bindings and templates.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell where you are going wrong without seeing more of the code. This is an example that works. It creates a new `LogWindow` in the `MainWindow` ctor and sets the DataContext. When the button is clicked the handler calls show on the window. The ListBox's itemssource property is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of strings. So any adds/removes are automatically updated on the UI.

LogWindows xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.LogWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="LogWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="DebugLogLb" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding LogText}" />
</Grid>
```

MainWindow code-behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    LogWindow _logWindow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LogText = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        _logWindow = new LogWindow();
        _logWindow.DataContext = this;
        _logWindow.Closed += _logWindow_Closed;
    }

    private void _logWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _logWindow = new LogWindow();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _logWindow.Show();

        LogText.Add("Button1 Clicked");
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> LogText { get; set; }
}
```